# ios production certificate about to expire, need to upload app again?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

My certificate expires in a month, my app uses push notifications so I need the certificate to be valid. If I revoke it and then create a new one will I have to upload an "update" for the app with the new certificate? or is easier if it expires first then I renew the certificate and  then I'll need to generate again all the provisionings with the new certificate? I need to be sure about this before I revoke it, please help. Can someone share a link where I can verify this.

Comment: I'll have to install the new certificate on the server that sends the push?

Answer (score 0):

No, not at all. The certificate is for your server. You don't need to submit an app update by any means, simply revoke the certificate and request a new one, and then upload that certificate to your provider, whether that be Urban Airship :) or whomever. No downtime whatsoever to your current users.